# Bulk CRUD operations from Redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, crud

We are writing an application using React and Redux libraries.

On the frontend, we have a React component that allow to add/delete *car brands* to a user 
For example:

```
bob: Toyota/Nissan/Chevrolet
tony: Toyota/BMW/Audi
```

Each brands has some custom parameters, so that a *car brand* can be either:

- ADDED
- MODIFIED
- REMOVED 
  from a specific user

We have a Redux state that contains the current list of brands for each users:

```
{
    brands_per_user:
    {
        bob: [Toyota,Nissan,Chevrolet],
        tony: [Toyota,BMW,Audi],
    }
}
```

On the backend, we have RESTful endpoints that accept GET/POST/PUT/DELETE operations:

```
{toyota,nissan,chevrolet}  ->   /api/users/bob/       
{toyota,bmw,audi}  ->            /api/users/tony/
```

We have a *Save button* that can allows to save the current Redux state to our backend.
So, when *Save* is pressed, the necessary CRUD operations should be triggered to APPEND/MODIFY/REMOVE the vehicules for each users.

Is there a popular, and easy way to acheive this with Redux ?

Our current approach, which is kind of cumbersome is to creates 3 kind of keys in the Redux state:

```
{
    brands_per_user:
    {
        bob: {
            added:  [Toyota, Chevrolet]
            modified:  [Nissan]
            deleted:  [Audi]
        },
        tony: {
            added:   [Toyota,Audi]
            modified:  [BMW]
            deleted:  [Nissan]
        },
    }
}
```

Once we hit the *Save* button, we trigger the CRUD operations for each of the sections *added*, *modified*, and *deleted*.
This approach works well in case of one component.
Our main problem is that we have multiple component that have to be saved when clicking this unique **Save** button.

Do you have any suggestion to simplify our approach?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve what you want. You want to handle complex (multi stepped) asynchronous API calls from action creators. These are two prominent options, which can help with that:

- [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) which allows actions creators to return promises (or chained-promises)
- [redux-saga](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-saga) which allows complex async control flows using coroutines